# PHP Adding and deleting sections in INI files

Tags: php, pear

I have a file which looks like this:

```
[account]
user=user1
pass=pass1

[account]
user=user2
pass=pass2

[account]
user=user3
pass=pass3
expdate=2016
```

I cant change the structure of this file. I'm looking for a way to basically interrogate this file and be able to add or edit or delete sections within it. For example:

Be able to delete an [account] section but only where user=user1

Show all accounts but only where expdate = 2016

I've tried pear's configlite but no joy :( really stuck. Any help appreciated!

Comment: check out `parse_ini_file` http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: its useless for what i need to do thats why i tried configlite. cheers

Comment: what exactly did you try? show us the code.